# Saving a string that contains both single and double quotes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, double-quotes, single-quotes

I am trying to a value in a string that contains both single and double quotes in javascript.  Is this possible without manually escaping some of the characters?  The string would look something like this:

```
var test = '<SCRIPT language='JavaScript1.1' SRC="www.website.com"> </SCRIPT>'
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn't just wrap 'Javascript1.1' in double quotes as well?

Comment: Use one type of quotes around the string, then just escape that same type inside.

Comment: P.S. `language='JavaScript1.1'` is ***long*** deprecated!  It's `type="text/javascript`.  Actually, in modern browsers, you can just do `<script src="www.website.com">`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat he said without escaping...

Comment: @KrakenDev: Then it's impossible.  Without "manually" escaping, it's a syntax error.  Depends where this "string" is coming from.  "Escaping" is *only* used when you are typing a string manually.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Ya I know, it's a strange question in general. He can either just use double quotes just like he did for the src attribute, or if for some reason he REALLY wants to keep single quotes for some reason and doesn't want to escape with '\' he would have to concatentate with + ' + .. Confusing either way.

Comment: @ZDROM: Can you explain *exactly* what you are trying to do here?  Where is this string coming from?  What do you mean by "without manually escaping"?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, So the problem is that I am not writing the code above. I am trying to save it to a var so I can manipulate it based on a couple different conditions. One solution I came up with was to encode it before saving it to the var but i was just wondering if there was any way to do this without that added initial step. I did find that if I encode the string and then save it to a var using decodeURIComponent it saves correctly with both single and double quotes.

Comment: @ZDROM: Where is this coming from?  How are you trying to "save it as a var"?

Comment: @RocketHazmat It is a snippet of code thats provided to me by a third party that I need to modify.  The pattern and the modification is consistent so I was hoping to save it as a string so I could then write a basic function to perform the swaps for me.